# Как узнать (Powershell, ...), что на удаленном Windows-сервере (2016/2019) после перезагрузки загрузился экран блокировки?

Tags: windows, powershell

Есть задача отследить готовность Windows-серверов после установки обновлений.
В простом случае этапы установки обновлений следующие:

1. Ручной запуск установки обновлений
2. Ручная перезагрузка сервера
3. Автоматическая доустановка обновлений
4. Экран блокировки

Но иногда сценарий бывает более сложным:

1. Ручной запуск установки обновлений
2. Ручная перезагрузка сервера
3. Автоматическая доустановка обновлений
4. Автоматическая перезагрузка сервера
5. Автоматическая доустановка обновлений
6. Экран блокировки

Во-время этапа Автоматической доустановки работают все те же службы, что и когда уже отобразился экран блокировки. Собственно вопрос в том как понять, что процесс установки обновлений завершился полностью (отображается экран блокировки), т.е. что все этапы "автоматической доустановки" завершены и автоматических перезагрузок больше не будет?
Пробовал отслеживать процесс TiWorker, но после появления экрана блокировки он иногда продолжает работать 5 минут (приемлемо), а иногда до нескольких часов (неприемлемо).

Comment: Я бы на твоём месте начал бы смотреть в сторону https://winitpro.ru/index.php/2018/10/01/pswindowsupdate-upravlenie-obnovleniyami-powershell/ У меня такая же проблема, только с десткопами и этот модуль - единственное, что щас есть нормального для руления обновами.

Comment: @don Rumata , спасибо за совет, но к сожалению, я не нашел как с помощью PSWindowsUpdate можно отследить предстоящие автоперезагрузки на этапе  автоматической доустановки обновлений (АДО). У PSWindowsUpdate есть Get-WURebootStatus, но в случае АДО он не помогает :(

Comment: Тогда пилить одельный скрипт с отдельным шедулером, который будет обходить список хостов и ставить там обновы.

Comment: "Тогда пилить отдельный скрипт", как раз написанием такого скрипта и занимаюсь :) Точнее скрипт уже есть и нормально работает, осталась решить только одну проблему - ту которой посвящена данная тема :) Спасибо.

Comment: Можно попробовать дергать там https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-openinputdesktop